# Listening to files in the pull requests on github

Tags: git, github, listener, monitoring, webhooks

I have a github repository of my project. Some users upload json file on my repo by pull requests. However, I only want to allow only special json files in my repo. I have one function which can tell if a given input json file is special or not. Whenever I receive a pull request, I want to make sure that the json file is special, if not, I want to notify the author of the PR that the file is not eligible for merge. I want to automate this process.

In addition, I also want to run a different script, when such open PRs are closed. I know about webhooks in github, but afaik, they provide very limited functionality. Using them, I can create a POST request to some server, with JSON payload. But, I want to access the files present in the PR, and run my special script on those files in the PR.

Can anyone suggest me a better approach for this? Thanks in advance :)